# Multi-dimensional array and explode function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

I'm having a hard time to get my desired output regarding multi-dimensional array please help me out thankssss

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "sku" : "11111",
        "qty" : "1"
    },
    {
        "sku" : "22222",
        "qty" : "1"
    },
    {
        "sku" : "33333",
        "qty" : "1"
    },
    {
        "sku" : "44444",
        "qty" : "1"
    }
]
```

---

My code:

```
$string = "11111*1; 22222*1; 33333*1; 44444*1";

$array  = explode('; ', $string);

foreach($array as $k=>$v){

  $array[$k] = explode('*', $v);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to fetch those values in two different variables and just assign it to new variable say `$result`

```
$string = "11111*1; 22222*1; 33333*1; 44444*1";
$array  = explode('; ', $string);
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    list($sku, $qty)   = explode('*', $v);
    $result[$k]['sku'] = $sku;
    $result[$k]['qty'] = $qty;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) — Returns the JSON representation of a value
[list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) — Assign variables as if they were an array

**Output**

```
[{
    "sku": "11111",
    "qty": "1"
}, {
    "sku": "22222",
    "qty": "1"
}, {
    "sku": "33333",
    "qty": "1"
}, {
    "sku": "44444",
    "qty": "1"
}]
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9bfc31b314c3881d2f5282c79b9ee3cde9e9685b).

**EDIT**

You can use [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to achieve the same.

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k]   = array_combine(['sku', "qty"],explode('*', $v));
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb087e9d3a6fc5334629ddb9bff44ade182bac37)

Comment: @noob_girl *Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in..*

Comment: @noob_girl Difference is if we don't write any index like I wrote `$k` in my code, it will assign default keys of array which starts with 0 to increasing length of array, and last index of any array will be length of array -1. Instead of all that, I took keys which are already created in first explode.

Comment: so the output will still be the same?

Comment: Yes but for your scenario

Answer (score 1):

`$key` is not required in [quickSwap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56079828/7499554) answer:

```
    $string = "11111*1; 22222*1; 33333*1; 44444*1";
    $array  = explode('; ', $string);
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        list($sku, $qty) = explode('*', $value);
        $result[] = [
            'sku' => $sku,
            'qty' => $qty
       ];
    }
```

Comment: What's the difference if there's a key or not tho?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently iterate through the object correctly, but you need to build your array in the correct way, containing the key names:

```
$string = "11111*1; 22222*1; 33333*1; 44444*1";
$array  = explode('; ', $string);
$new    = [];

foreach($array as $k => $v){
    $parts = explode('*', $v);

    $new[] = [
        'sku' => $parts[0],
        'qty' => $parts[1],
    ];
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/DnPJk)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to loop thru the exploded string. Use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert the array into a json

```
$string = "11111*1; 22222*1; 33333*1; 44444*1";

$result = array_map(function($v){
    $t =  explode("*", $v);
    return array( "sku" => trim( $t[0] ), "qty" => trim( $t[1] ));      
}, explode(";", $string));

echo json_encode( $result );
```

This will result to:

```
[{
  "sku": "11111",
  "qty": "1"
}, {
  "sku": "22222",
  "qty": "1"
}, {
  "sku": "33333",
  "qty": "1"
}, {
  "sku": "44444",
  "qty": "1"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk`, `explode` and `json_encode` with parameter `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
$string = "11111*1; 22222*1; 33333*1; 44444*1";
$strToArray = explode(';',$string);
$res=[];
array_walk($strToArray, function($v, $k) use (&$res){
  $res[$k] = [
    'sku' => substr($v, 0, strpos($v, '*')),
    'qty' => substr($v,strpos($v, '*')+1, strlen($v))
  ];
});
echo json_encode($res,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/0QRSE)